# Synchronization with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, synchronization

Sup guys !

I'm currently have some problems about the synchronization with JavaScript. It's about a refresh. When it reach 10 second i refresh an array.

```
var curD = new Date();
if((curD.getTime() / 1000) - dMList[i].startTime > dMList[i].refreshTime)
{
    dMList[i].elem = new Array();
    RSSDropMenuConstructor(dMList[i]);
    dMList[i].startTime = curD.getTime() / 1000;
}

sendResponse({ getdropMenuFields: dMList[i] }); // Send the appropiate dropMenu
```

Function RSS

```
function RSSDropMenuConstructor(dMObject)
{
    jQuery.getFeed({
       url: dMObject.rssLink,
       success: function(feed) {

        for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < dMObject.maxItem; i++) {

            var item = feed.items[i];

            field = new Object();               
            field.name = 'text';
            field.value = item.title;
            dMObject.elem.push(field);

            field = new Object();
            field.name = 'weblink';
            field.value = item.link;
            dMObject.elem.push(field);

            field = new Object();
            field.name = 'icon';
            field.value = 'http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1305270873/images/embed/bullet-feed.png';
            dMObject.elem.push(field);
        }          

        dMList.push(dMObject);
   }
});
```

So the RSSDropMenuConstructor will construct the dMList[i].elem, but the problem is that then "SendReponse" don't wait the end of the function.

So what it happend, when it refresh i received an empty array because the array is not yet initialized... Somebody have an idea how i can synchronize this ?

Comment: can you post some more code ? is this given code in a function ? how you are calling the function ?

Comment: I don't really get why the sendResponse call is outside of the if statement. Do you call this periodically ?

Comment: Yeah, it's because, if i need to refresh or not, in both case i need to send a response

Comment: Is dmList global ? Seeing the calling code for the first bit would help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the feed to come back from the server before calling sendResponse(). Place the call to sendResponse() in the callback function (that is, function(feed){...}).

Because AJAX is asynchronous, Javascript will continue to execute your code, even while a request to the server is pending. The callback, on the other hand, does not execute until the server responds.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sendReponse() function inside the if statement. That way it will execute when the rest of the code inside that block is executing.

Comment: Without knowing what else you are calling, it's hard to help any further.